# How to write calculated field formula in AWS QuickSight using ifelse

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to write a formula that would calculate a discounted cost depending on the date.

Any costs that accrue after May 2019 would have a discount rate of 7% and anything prior to that would be 6%.

This is what I have for the formula but it's saying the syntax is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ifelse(month >= 5 AND year >= 2019), then {unblended_cost} - ({unblended_cost} * 0.07), else {unblended_cost} - ({unblended_cost} * 0.06))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following and let me know if you encounter other errors

```
ifelse(                                                                         
  month >= 5 AND year >= 2019,                                                  
  {unblended_cost} - ({unblended_cost} * 0.07),                                 
  {unblended_cost} - ({unblended_cost} * 0.06)                                  
)
```

Essentially `ifelse` can be thought of as a single function, and the `then` and `else` keywords are extraneous.

Comment: Yes this worked out perfectly. Thanks! It’s weird the way that they format their SQL queries

Comment: Function documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/ifelse-function.html